# How to save paragraph without linebreak

Tags: c#, docx, doc

i'm trying to create some *.docx documents using Novacode. And I need to have few other text foratting in one specific line. I think it can be made as others paragraphs, but all of thm end with new line break. And I can't deal with it, how to remove that. Can you have any suggestions? Or maybe is other, easier solution for my problem?

Comment: Can you show us the code you're working with?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I recommend reading [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as this will users answer your question and futures readers understand the question.

Comment: [link]http://pastebin.com/yT3gncCP
And I want that the letters before '-' are bigger and in bold, and letters after it are in normal font.

Comment: I have no experience with NovaCode, but most probably there is something like a TextRun or Span class, which you can insert into a Paragraph. Set the font size and font weight for the seperate elements and add them into a Paragraph sequentially - also, read Erik Philips' comment and improve your question.

Comment: Yes, I guess, that can be something like TextRun or Span class, but I can't find it. And I think it's the bigger problem here.

Comment: Ok, I found it. In Paragraph class we have method insertText(string value, bool trackChanges, Formatting formatting), but earlier my VS didn't show me that in tips. Thank you so much for help.

Comment: Is this: https://docx.codeplex.com/ the library you're using ?